# How to SetValue using UIA in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ui-automation

Below code is to set the to-be-translated content in Excel.
The program gets stucked when it goes to the line `oPattern.SetValue ("自動機器")`.
The control type is `UIA_EditControlTypeId (0xC354)`, and also is allowed to set value.
So what is the right way to set the value?
[image]

```vb
Dim oAutomation As New CUIAutomation
Dim WinElements As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement
Dim EleTransSrc As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement
Dim EleTransRslt As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement

Sub UIADemo()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim oInvokePattern As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationInvokePattern
    Dim oPattern As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern
    
    Set WinElements = WalkEnabledElements(oAutomation.GetRootElement, "VBA_Translation.xlsm - Excel")
    Debug.Print WinElements.CurrentName
    Set EleTransSrc = WinElements.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, PropCondition(oAutomation, 1, "translation-textfield-idsrc"))
    
    Set oPattern = EleTransSrc.GetCurrentPattern(UIAutomationClient.UIA_LegacyIAccessiblePatternId)
    oPattern.SetValue ("自動機器")

ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print "get stucked"
End Sub

Function PropCondition(UiAutomation As CUIAutomation, Prop As Integer, Requirement As String) As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition
    Select Case Prop
        Case 0
            Set PropCondition = UiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_NamePropertyId, Requirement)
        Case 1
            Set PropCondition = UiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_AutomationIdPropertyId, Requirement)
        Case 2
            Set PropCondition = UiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_ClassNamePropertyId, Requirement)
        Case 3
            Set PropCondition = UiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_LocalizedControlTypePropertyId, Requirement)
    End Select
End Function

Function WalkEnabledElements(element As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement, strWindowName As String) As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement
    Dim walker As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationTreeWalker
    Set walker = oAutomation.ControlViewWalker
    Set element = walker.GetFirstChildElement(element)
    
    Do While Not element Is Nothing
        'Debug.Print element.CurrentName
        If InStr(1, element.CurrentName, strWindowName) > 0 Then
            Set WalkEnabledElements = element
            Exit Function
        End If
    
        Set element = walker.GetNextSiblingElement(element)
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: What does it mean for the program to get stucked?

Comment: The program is excuting the line for long time (if Ctrl+ Pause not been pressed, it continues running) and there's no response. Everything in Excel is freezed. Just like some fetal error happens.